# How to avoid internalError on load Cloud Storage files to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I get internalError when load Google Cloud Storage files.

```
$ bq load --source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON xx_20150430 gs://xxxx/yyyy.gz
```

Job status is

```
{
    "state": "DONE",
    "errorResult": {
        "reason": "internalError",
        "message": "Backend error. Job aborted."
    }
}
```

Even if I retry to load same file, it fails.

```
$ bq load --source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON xx_20150430 gs://xxxx/yyyy.gz
Errors encountered during job execution. Backend error. Job aborted.
# Retry
$ bq load --source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON xx_20150430 gs://xxxx/yyyy.gz
Errors encountered during job execution. Backend error. Job aborted.
```

I run 48 load jobs with the same GCS-bucket and same data format every day. Then about 4~5 of jobs are failed. I couldn't find the invalid data record. I'm using the same GCP Project and GCS bucket since January 2015, this internalError get after April-8.

But I found a workaround. (Once download to local and load it)

```
$ bq load --source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON xx_20150430 gs://xxxx/yyyy.gz
Errors encountered during job execution. Backend error. Job aborted.
$ gsutil cp gs://xxxx/yyyy.gz ./yyyy.gz
$ bq load --source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON xx_20150430 ./yyyy.gz
SUCCESS
```

### Sumarry

- I'm getting internalError everyday since April 8.
- About 10% Jobs are failed by internalError. (I make 48 load jobs every day which uses the same GCS-bucket)
- Even If I retry the failed job, I get internalError every time.
- Download the file which causes internalError from CloudStorage and load it using bq command. Then success.

### Additional Information

My project id is vg-zucks-zgok and one of JobId is zgok_deliver_log_production-rd_20150427-5920de503013708e38505aa2a936f48f8ea44c374eebe72346c2376b21607fce

Comment: You should reach out to support, as this sounds to me a bug and your project is affected. Could you also provide the project name, so if someone from BQ will see could look into.

Comment: Thanks, I added my project id and BQ load job id.

Comment: Just to be sure, you store the file in cloud under the same project id, right? This way BQ has read access to the file you store on GCS.

Comment: Yes I stored files to GCS-bucket under the same project.

Comment: You have encountered a bug in BigQuery's handling of this request. Given the specifics of this failure, it may take me a while to figure out the root cause-- sorry about that. As a possible work-around for you: can you try splitting the single .gz file into two or three .gz files and see if that works? (This will increase throughput of your load job as well.)

Comment: After investigating further: there is nothing obviously wrong with your load jobs. Do you have a reproducible error? If you start a new job against the same uri and the new job fails, then can you please reach out to me at msheldon@google.com? Thank you.

Comment: Fortunately there is no internalError since the beginning of May. (Last one is Apr. 30 AM3 UTC)
I don't know why it fixed, I didn't change anything my program.